# How do I remove a background from a sprite in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using this spritesheet here: https://www.mariouniverse.com/wp-content/img/sprites/nes/smb/enemies-8.png. Then I would use JavaScript and use drawImage().However, I don't know how to remove the background of the image using JavaScript.

I've tried to use background removers, but when I tried it for a Goomba, it chopped off the feet and the background.
Code would be something like this:

```
<img src="https://www.mariouniverse.com/wp-content/img/sprites/nes/smb/enemies-8.png" height="0" width="0" id="enemies">
<script>
  const enemies = document.getElementById("enemies");
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  c.drawImage(enemies, 0, 18, 16, 16, 0, 0, 16, 16);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? Possibly a snippet or a fiddle and then edit your question so we could play around with that in order to solve it for you?

Comment: You copy a rectangle of data, then you run through the pixels (lots of answers for how to do that on SO already) and set every pixel with the background color to have an alpha value of 0.

Comment: How do you copy a rectangle of data? Can you show a code snippet so I can understand better? I also don't understand how you set every pixel to have an "alpha" value of 0.

Comment: Also plenty of SO answers for that already, easily found with a search (and the Canvas API is pretty well documented with loads of good tutorials on the web, too).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm still very confused. Can you provide a link to a tutorial or a link to a question on Stackoverflow?

Comment: [Just search?](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+draw+sprites+on+canvas+using+spritesheet) You're not the first person to want to use spritesheets on a page canvas, so there are plenty of tutorials out there for you to find and read, and searching will find you way more than I can link to in a comment (ignoring the fact that requests for links is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here, because today's link may be a 404 tomorrow, making the comment useless for future visitors)